# transpose the columns of csv file in particular format excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, excel-2016

Hi I am new to csv so I don't know much about it. My csv file is in the form of

```
 n1 q1 a1
 n2 q2 a2
 n3 q3 a3
```

I want to convert it in the form of

```
n1 sentence q1
n1 reply    a1
n1 format   {"type":"text"}
n2 sentence q2
n2 reply    a2
n2 format   {"type":"text"}
n3 sentence q3
n3 reply    a3
n3 format   {"type":"text"}
```

I thought of trying using transpose and pivot table but it is not coming the way I want. Is it possible to convert it in the above form in excel?

Comment: Where does sentence, reply and format come from? When I first read this, I though N represented a Row_Nbr, and each row had one question and one answer. I'm a little confused by this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/), you can run

```
mlr --nidx label id,sequence,reply then put '$format="{\"type\":\"text\"}"' then reshape -i sequence,reply,format -o k,v input.txt
```

to get

```
n1 sequence q1
n1 reply a1
n1 format {"type":"text"}
n2 sequence q2
n2 reply a2
n2 format {"type":"text"}
n3 sequence q3
n3 reply a3
n3 format {"type":"text"}
```

It's a wide to long trasformation.